# How to shift table in markdown file?

Tags: tfs, markdown

I have a table in README.md file in TFS like this:

```
| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |
```

It's work. But I need to shift this table to the right by tab character. And if I place tab (or space character) before table rows it's not recognize as table and just print as plain text. HTML tag  also doesn't work in TFS.

How I can move table?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: No, It's still unresolved

Comment: Ah, as I described in below answer, shift table is not supported in Markdown. So no solution with Markdown itself.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately shift table is not supported in Markdown.

Markdown does not provide any special syntax for tables.

Please see [Syntax guidance for Markdown files, widgets, wikis, and pull request comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/collaborate/markdown-guidance#tables) for details.

I can think of is that you can capture a screenshot for the table, render the captured image, check in the image, then [Add image to your Markdown file](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/collaborate/markdown-guidance#images).

But please note that just as Waylan mention in below comments : *For screenshot of a table, the text will no longer be searchable and cannot be copy and pasted by the user. And any future edits will require recreating the entire table.*

Comment: Suggesting using a screenshot of a table is bad advice. The text will no longer be searchable and cannot be copy and pasted by the user. And any future edits will require recreating the entire table. -1

Comment: @Waylan So, could you provide a better suggestion or a solution?

Comment: Not sifting the table at all would be better than embedding it in an image.

Comment: @Waylan I agree with your concerns, but for this question **Not shifting** means nothing, as the question is `"How to shift table in markdown file?"` Whatever, thanks for your comments.